# error: unknown type name 'ClassObject'

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am trying to replace android system call with my custom method using android native code, by googling I found few blogs but while trying given code I am getting errors.

by following the blog

I am Creating android Native method using following code from this [blog](http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-replacing-system-classes.html?showComment=1403614826998#c9216339405705276171)

```
#include "com_appwrapping_tunneling_SimpleActivity.h"

int Java_com_appwrapping_tunneling_SimpleActivity_swap_1virtual_1methods(char *origclass, char *origmeth, char *newclass, char *newmeth) {
  int i = 0;
  ClassObject *newclazz = g_dvmfindloadedclass(newclass);
  if (!newclazz) {
    return 0;
  }
  ClassObject *oldclazz = g_dvmfindclass(origclass, newclazz->classLoader);
  if (!oldclazz) {
    return 0;
  }
  struct Method *oldm = NULL, *newm = NULL;
  if (newclazz) {
    for (i = 0; i < newclazz->vtableCount; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(newclazz->vtable[i]->name, newmeth))
           // this is the new method
           newm = newclazz->vtable[i];
    }
  }
  if (oldclazz) {
    for (i = 0; i < oldclazz->vtableCount; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(oldclazz->vtable[i]->name, origmeth)) {
           // save old method
           oldm = oldclazz->vtable[i];
           // put new method in place of old
           oldclazz->vtable[i] = newm;
        }
    }
  }
  if (!newm || !oldm) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, MYLOG_TAG, "failed to find methods/objects");
    return 0;
  }
  // add some space for original method
  oldclazz->vtable = g_dvmlinearrealloc(oldclazz->classLoader,
                      oldclazz->vtable,
                      sizeof(*(oldclazz->vtable)) * (oldclazz->vtableCount + 1));
  // we put it at the end of the table
  oldclazz->vtableCount++;
  oldclazz->vtable[oldclazz->vtableCount - 1] = oldm;
  // now new method gets old method name
  newm->name = oldm->name;
  char *fname = NULL;
  // leaking memory here
  fname = (char*) malloc(strlen(origmeth) + strlen(FAKE_PREFIX) + 1);
  sprintf(fname, "%s%s", FAKE_PREFIX, origmeth);
  // now old method will get _orig_ prefix, so it can be looked up later
  oldm->name = fname;
  // swap method indexes
  newm->methodIndex = oldm->methodIndex;
  // now old method gets proper index
  oldm->methodIndex = oldclazz->vtableCount - 1;
  g_dvmdumpclass(oldclazz, 1);
  g_dvmdumpclass(newclazz, 1);
  __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, MYLOG_TAG, "swap successful!");
  return 1;
}
```

All things going fine but while generating .so file using following command :

```
<NDK-Home>$ ndk-build
```

I getting this following error:

```
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c: In function 'swap_1virtual_1methods':
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:6:3: error: unknown type name 'ClassObject'
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:6:27: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:10:3: error: unknown type name 'ClassObject'
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:10:61: error: request for member 'classLoader' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:14:25: error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:14:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:16:29: error: request for member 'vtableCount' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:17:28: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:19:27: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:23:29: error: request for member 'vtableCount' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:24:28: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:26:27: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:28:20: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:33:25: error: 'ANDROID_LOG_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:33:44: error: 'MYLOG_TAG' undeclared (first use in this function)
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:37:11: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:37:49: error: request for member 'classLoader' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:38:31: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:39:40: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:39:62: error: request for member 'vtableCount' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:41:11: error: request for member 'vtableCount' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:42:11: error: request for member 'vtable' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:42:28: error: request for member 'vtableCount' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:44:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:44:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:47:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:47:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen' [enabled by default]
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:47:52: error: 'FAKE_PREFIX' undeclared (first use in this function)
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:48:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'sprintf' [enabled by default]
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:50:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:52:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:52:27: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:54:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:54:31: error: request for member 'vtableCount' in something not a structure or union
JNIApp/jni/testLib.c:57:23: error: 'ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [JNIApp/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/testLib/testLib.o] Error 1
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the method 'g_dvmfindloadedclass', I never saw methods like this

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are getting are caused by the compiler being unable to find a valid definition of the symbols that you have included in your application. The most likely cause of this is that you have forgotten to include `jni.h` in your implementation code.

```
#include <jni.h>
```

make sure as well that the `jni.h` file is on your `include-path` (once you have added the above line). If you had included it but your compiler could not find it then your error would indicate that.

`jni.h` is included in the JDK packages from Oracle. You may need one specific to the JVM that Android uses though.

**EDIT**

The symbols you are trying to use are not JNI symbols ... I was thinking of `jclass`. `ClassObject` is the internal representation of a `class` in the Dvorak Virtual Machine. From here:

> On Dalvik all Java class/object mapping to native C structs is happening in vm/oo/* files. Object instances are mirrored with ClassObject structs, and methods with Methods.
>   So each ClassObject comes with 2d vtable array, which simply contains pointers to Methods.

So you need to include the Dvorak VM headers from `vm/oo/`. You are attempting to directly manipulate the internals of the VM. You should probably read that article again to make sure you picked it all up.

Comment: This can be a comment

Comment: @CasperSky @Brian This `could` be left as a comment but it is the answer to the question. I will expand it a little though.

Comment: @IndraYadav - Show your code (not from the website) completely.

Comment: @Dennis.. I have posted the code..  look forward for your answer.

Comment: @Dennis The ClassObject Declared here in vm/oo/Object.h, I tried to include all possible header files like globals.h, Object.h but could not succeed..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56263/discussion-between-dennis-and-indra-yadav).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem. I got stuck at this point where when compiling c library I got these errors saying ClassObject not found etc etc. So I dug deep and found that these header files object.h and class.h were previously part of [vm/oo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/oo/) directory until android Kitkat. When Dalvik VM was almost buried, these files were deleted in and after [Lollipop](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/870b4f2d70d67d6dbb7d0881d101c61bed8caad2) release.

As you might have already found out swizelling methods in android is extremely difficult and not worth the time if you have *any* alternatives.
*I have not found a method to do it on ART so please comment if you have come across any*